# How to get location from service

Tags: android, service, location

Somewhat new to android, need some help with services. I have a service which polls for current location at interval X. I want to bind to that service and pass getLastKnownLocation from the service to my Activity A. I am not sure exactly how the information is passed from the bound service to the activity, if its through the binder or what. Anyways, here is my code where I am at thus far.

Service:

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements LocationListener {


    LocationManager myLocationManager;
    public Location myLocation;
    LocationListener myLocationListener;
    public static final String TAG = LocationService.class.getSimpleName();
    MyDB db;
    double latitude,longitude;
    Cursor c;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "service started (onCreate)");
        db = new MyDB(getApplicationContext());
        myLocationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_LOW);
        String locationProvider = myLocationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationProvider, 1000*60*2, 100, this);
        myLocation = myLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);


    }
 public class MyBinder extends Binder {
            LocationService getService() {
                return LocationService.this;
            }
        }
```

Activity A:

```
public class myActivity extends Activity {
    LocationManager myLocationManager;
    Location myLocation;

    boolean isBound = false;

    private LocationService mBoundService;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        bindLocationService();

}
private void bindLocationService() {
        try {
            isBound = getApplicationContext().bindService( new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationService.class), mConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE );
            bindService(new Intent(this, LocationService.class), mConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            mBoundService = ((LocationService.MyBinder)service).getService();
            Log.d(LocationService.TAG, "activity bound to service");

        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {

            mBoundService = null;
            Log.d(LocationService.TAG, "activity unbound to service");
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: To get a Location all you need is to implement LocationListener and start listening, it's performed in a separate thread anyway. Do you have any particular reason for using Service here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Send a Broadcast from your service like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(NEW_MESSAGE);  
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("yourvalue", value);
i.putExtras(bundle);
sendBroadcast(i);
```

and register for receiver in your activity like this:

```
newMessage messageReceiver = new newMessage();
registerReceiver(messageReceiver, new IntentFilter(NEW_MESSAGE));
```

This is your receiver in your activity class:

```
public class newMessage extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {    
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(action.equalsIgnoreCase(IMService.NEW_MESSAGE)){    
        Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();
        String username = extra.getString("yourvalue");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For Communicate between Service and your Activity Create Custom `BroadcastReceiver` and broadcast it from Service every time when you want to update your Activity with Intent which content new location info.like

```
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(CUSTOM_INTENT);
    context.sendBroadcast(i);
```

see this [example](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/custom-intents-and-broadcasting-with-receivers/) for custom Broadcast

Answer (score 0):

You have to "subscribe" your `Activity` to the `Service` it binds. The `Service` can receive an object of type `Messenger` via the `Intent` data it receives from the `Activity`.
So you can define a simple `Handler` inside your `Activity` and a `Messenger` that uses it. This way the `Service` can send objects of type `Message` to the `Activity`, shipping all the info you need inside the `Message` itself.